# Best practice for handling errors inside a service in a reusable way

Tags: nestjs

I just started to learn `nestjs` from the official course from the creator.But, there is something that i don't really like: It's way service http exceptions are thrown from the service.Here is an example:

```
@Injectable()
export class CoffeeService{
...
findOne(id:string){
    const coffee=this.coffees.find(item=>item.id===+id);
    if(!coffee){ 
        throw new NotFoundException(`Coffee #${id} not found`) 
    }
    return coffee;
 }
...
}
```

So what i don't like is the way `NotFoundException` is used inside this service.

Imagine that i'de to reuse this for with other kinds of protocols like `websocket` or `grpc` that may not understand this kinds of http status, what should i do?

Isn't the http controller the best place to throw this specific http Exceptions?

Maybe i've not yet understood how `nestjs` works under the hood, but it seems to note be a good pratice.

I would like to have some ideas of ways a good practice of how and where to handle Errors in `nestjs`.

Comment: you could raise domain errors and catch them on exceptions filters bound to controllers so you can reply with a proper http status code and so on

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom exception classes and then handle them in your code like below:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
    constructor(msg: string) {
        super(msg);

        // Set the prototype explicitly.
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, FooError.prototype);
    }
}
```

then in your service or anywhere else:

```
if(!coffee){ 
        throw new CustomError(`Coffee #${id} not found`) 
}
```